# strange thing in perl's eval function

Tags: perl

I get the following warning:

> "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at C:\tools\test.pl line 17, DATA line 1."

But the next line of `__DATA__` will be processed without any warning and get these:

> test1b.txt:test test1c.txt:test :test

More strange thing is that when I add a line: `print "$line:".$'."\n";` The warning disappeared.

Anybody have some clues?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $pattern='test';
my $output='$&';
while(<DATA>)
{
    chomp;
    my $line=$_;
    chomp($line);
    $line=~/$pattern/;
    #print "$line:".$&."\n";   #why uncommenting this line make the following line pass without no warning.
    my $result="$line:".eval($output)."\n";
    print $result;
}

__DATA__
test1a.txt
test1b.txt
test1c.txt
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl considers `$&`, `$'`, and `` $` `` to be expensive, so it won't actually populate them in a program that doesn't use them. From the `perlvar` manpage:

> The use of this variable [`$&`] anywhere in a program imposes a considerable
>   performance penalty on all regular expression matches.  To avoid this
>   penalty, you can extract the same substring by using `@-`.  Starting
>   with Perl 5.10, you can use the `/p` match flag and the `${^MATCH}`
>   variable to do the same thing for particular match operations.

However, when you only use them inside a string that you pass to `eval`, Perl can't *tell* that you're using them, so it won't populate them, so they'll be undefined.

Comment: Good point! I rarelly use 'eval'. Some links give more notion about its usage, such as, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909127/perl-why-doesnt-eval-set-1.